# Mutable<T> works only when there's an missing type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I created a **Mutable** type utility which intended to convert immutable structures to mutable ones. This includes `readonly xxx[]` types as well as the `Readonly<T>` operators. In my local environment it wasn't working and so I copied it to a TS Playground and to my shock and horror it worked perfectly. Then I noticed that my type util was dependent on a type utility that didn't exist. I'd have thought I'd end up with an *any* type or something equally as ugly but no ... it worked.

Here's that state of the playground: [Working when Broken](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwKIA8wFMDGMA0ckCOArgIYA2AvnAGZQQhwBEAAjAJ4YC0mAFuWegB2Ac3QBnAPREYwMmMYBuAFBL0aaPHYY4AWWkkARgIA8AFQB8cALyIlcOJyjoSAEwiCybOAG0A0nGBBOABrdDYIajhTAF0ALjgASTEAeQMAKywYMz9oyzUYIRcxOBgoInQ4O3s4AH5dfSN0bN9cyuq4eNMcuHzC4oAlZzcPNmMSQTZzKva6rpaelALBIrhB13dPY0DqdChVqfaZ1enD+MF0ADddk-tOnOUKZSUtCtNxGABGa1WhjdGEKrUCAQM5EEAGXbKewGEhQeJrYabRhscSMOAAHyYgggjHMULgMIAXvEnOsRnAxKVAsJvNEHnjnhxXu8AEzfAH2IEguCCMEQqD4mFwn5kpEo+QYrE4hnQkjEuCkxFeSlQam0h5PF5Rd4AZm+ir+PkYXMYeEYQsYdMZ2jelIALPrfuSVWqrdaKslpJh6OgvjY9DBDCZbZ8GVrPTBvSB0Gz-Q1g6yw0y4BGo+g9XHA40zLqk9pUz6HZmg00Q3aGe64JgSGJxN9vFVUBhsMZCKQyMYC9GPngEDRgaDwZCCbD4sjUZLGNjFCP5S6RLTJQbnVSF9E4BRzOY8BIJAqnZ44BB0pk4AB3YAwHj70VeMB0MCNtCZVvEcidr0+lm9-vc3lDgUR2FccJUxKccQUWd4nnGl10xZdDxgxdN23OBdzgEB4wqY8Mmwc9L2vBC7wfJ9myyNt3y7dM8G8Y1gVNJgLVyVD0JgIgwAEUiXwojsqLtPAkOYnc91hKASDYJQ6SAA)

The code for Mutate is:

```
export type Mutable<T> = {
  -readonly [K in keyof T]: IsObject<T[K]> extends true 
    ? Mutable<T[K]> 
    : T[K] extends Readonly<any>
      ? T[K] extends Readonly<infer R>
        ? R
        : never
      : T[K];
};
```

This code relies on a the `IsObject` utility which I created but forgot to bring into the playground above. This utility looks like this:

```
type IsObject<T> = Mutable<T> extends Record<string, any>
  ? T extends <A extends any[]>(...args: A) => any
    ? false  // when a function with props is found, categorize as a function not object
    : true
  : false;
```

The new playground with previously missing *IsObject* now included: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwKIA8wFMDGMA0ckCOArgIYA2AvnAGZQQhwBEAAjAJ4YC0mAFuWegB2Ac3QBnAPREYwMmMYBuAFBL0aaPHYY4ASTEB5AEYArLDAA8AFQB8cALxwAstJKGBV22phCAJmLgASljQPuZiMFDAIngkgmzWSnBwAPxwlnBevv7mAIIZKN6CfnCxbADaALrWABQAdPUkUMJiAFxwOQCU9raliUkpNORi6EkSEnAA7jxCJTREgtjAEIKTwDA8cGB0YP7A-tQQ8z54mCTewtDAAF4jJP4kcwsyy3CCEPAQJmZ9SW0RROg+m1qEN0MpVOpYHAtCNnDBXO4bPZEH1OFB0CQfMsyGw4GUANJwKJwADW6DYEGoaQqbT0RlM2CsBKq+UKxX+Ix+AzhCPQTPxLK5bUszNZWUCGKxghx5lKCX6-VSIoFYqK-iCmOxbHMUWo6CggXlCsVgS5CragnQADd9Wa4MLmcoKOCYWlxDAAIzIjVSmUIPoHCAWoggQz65RJQyNNo+rXmRhscSMOAAHyYb0Y1gjcCjVza6M10tx4UiIkqTqzSldlndACZkf6koHg6Hw30o1AY5K4wmk6n0xBM9nc-nu0W4CWosJy0pnSpq+6AMzIgu+3FlRiBxh4RgdxgVZQL8IAFhXY5xE4iU5nVY4I300kw9HQXocPLcfJr4Q9lddD5gT4gOg9Zvi4H5WHWv53nA-6Aegy6gfC4FfjAi5QdosHPqeiG8hBJ6Vre2inMM-gOGUfSoBgjKEKQZDmJhQEengCA0BAQavCGYZQAoObRkwibyP2jAZjxI6XqW04VP2q5auJ15SRQ1jWHgYxwDJ46fAy8ATGsGzqReWwQGAFFoGY5g0eQ9GPs+tbMax7GCJx4a8Z2-F9mmwmDqJJB5nJZZSWm+nFle-lwIpylwKpIBgQIcCaWYqzrGp564oZxlJJRZkWXRDHwXgG5bjue5VBFqkwEQYACCZVEWNlVkAVheCTv5SkqeMjRQCQbBKAeShAA)

Sadly, the first two tests are no longer passing:
[image: failing tests]

The types passed into these two first tests were similar:

[image: test data]

These passed to `Mutate<T>` produce the same results and some useful conversion has been made but while `baz` was converted to from a *readonly* array to a mutable array, the property `bar` remains with the `Readonly<"yes" | "no">`

[image]

Can anyone help me understand how to remove these `Readonly<T>` props? Can anyone explain how it all works when I use a non-existing type utility?

---

Adding to comments ...

example of constraints on use of `readonly` modifier:
[image: limits of modifier]

Comment: `Readonly<"yes" | "no">` does not really make much sense in the first place. What do you think is the result when TypeScript tries to compute this generic type?

Comment: The first playground is not actually working, the `IsObject` in underlined, the second playground will work when you remove the ` | readonly string[]` part which is the result you should expect.

Comment: The problem is not `Readonly<"yes" | "no">` but that you are expecting `string[] | readonly string[]` as the type of `baz`. Remove `readonly string[]` and the tests pass. The fact that typescript shows you `Readonly<"yes" | "no">` as the type of `bar` field is fine, it ultimately resolves to just `"yes" | "no"`

Comment: You don't need `IsObject<~>` you can also do something like this `type Mutable<T> = T extends object ? { -readonly [K in keyof T]: Mutable<T[K]> } : T`

Comment: @Filly your suggestion fails in the same way mine does

Comment: @TobiasS. not sure why you mean by `Readonly<"yes" | "no">` not making sense. In what way doesn't it? It indicates to developers that this field is one of two literals and that they are not mutable.

Comment: @AlexChashin your conclusion is partially correct ... yes you're right that the test passes but the `Readonly<T>` annotation remains.

Comment: @ryskajakub I think that was the point I was trying to make :)

Comment: @TobiasS. while I know that this annotation is not going to _prevent_ people from mutating the property I do think it creates cognitive disonance in something I'd prefer to be clear

Comment: @ken - strings are always immutable in JavaScript. You maybe want to make the *field* `readonly` like `readonly bar: "yes" | "no"`? If you check the implementation of `Readonly`. It is *not* an intrinsic type. Its just a mapped type which makes all properties `readonly`. When passing a string literal to `Readonly`, one might expect that it just returns the literal type which was passed into it. But the `readonly` part of the mapped type propably confuses the compiler a bit. So it does not really compute the result of this type at all and just leaves it as `Readonly<"yes" | "no">`

Comment: @TobiasS. i'm referring to a _string_ field on an object. This _can_ be set to being immutable in Javascript with `Object.defineProperty()` and the `readonly` attribute in TS can only be applied to arrays and tuples not to scalars.

Comment: @ken - no, `readonly` works with all kinds of property types: `readonly bar: "yes" | "no"`

Comment: @TobiasS. I've updated the question at the bottom to show what I'm talking about

Comment: The `readonly` goes before the property name, as shown in my comment above.

Comment: Ok, indeed you are right. Still find it odd that I _could_ remove the Readonly<T> when I had an error in my TS utility but not when I removed it but I can live with this.

Comment: Having errors or undefined types leads mostly to undefined behaviour. I am not sure if an investigation into this issue is worth it.

Comment: No I won't be but it gave me a hope I could remove this artifact as well

Answer (score 2):

Having gotten a very useful push in the right direction from @TobaisS. I have now created this type which recursively and cleanly addresses the problem space for instances of the `readonly` modifier and accepts that for now the `Readonly<T>` modifier is not an absolute requirement (though it is still on my "nice-to-have" list.

```
/**
 * Makes a readonly structure mutable
 */
export type Mutable<T> = ExpandRecursively<{
  -readonly [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends {} 
    ? Mutable<T[K]> 
    : T[K] extends readonly (infer R)[]
      ? R[]
      : T[K];
}>;
```

Where the `ExpandResursively<T>` utility is used to unwrap the recursion and give a clean type. It looks like this:

```
export type ExpandRecursively<T> = T extends object
  ? T extends (...args: any[]) => any
    // Functions should be treated like any other non-object value
    // but will/can identify as an object in JS
    ? T
    : { [K in keyof T]: ExpandRecursively<T[K]> }
  : T;
```

With these two utilities you can take a recursive input like so:

```
type T = {
  foo: number;
  bar: readonly string[];
  readonly baz: string;
  nested: {
    one: number;
    readonly two: number;
    readonly literal: "foo" | "bar";
  };
};
```

and convert with `Mutable<T>` to:

```
{
  foo: number;
  bar: string[];
  baz: string;
  nested: {
    one: number;
    two: number;
    literal: "foo" | "bar";
  };
}
```